# How does compiler restrict methods in an interface?

Tags: java

How does compiler restrict methods in an interface? If we take a look at the following example of Spring-data-jpa where `findByOrganizationName()` is a valid method, but `x()` complains since `x` is not a property of `Organization`. How does the compiler know that?

How can we design something similar in Java?

```
@Repository
public interface OrganizationRepository extends JpaRepository<Organization, Long>, 
        QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Organization> {

    List<Organization> findByOrganizationName(String organizationName);

    String x();  // Invalid derived query! No property x found for type Organization!
}
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Spring, do you use any compiler plugins for preprocessing? If so, that might be how Spring detects this.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend compiler behaviour by writing your own annotation processor. You can start from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/hunter-meta-3-092019.html)